# best practice: postgres table bloat monitoring

Tags: postgresql

I want to introduce monitoring for table bloat to our postgres databases.

Researching on the internet, there seem to be two ways:

1. Use `pgstattuple`. This seems to be the preferred approach BUT seems to do a FTS of all tables in the DB.
2. Use a query that detects bloat based on analyze-data such as [this query](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat) BUT that seems to be out of favour nowadays.

What would you consider best practice for a weekly job that scans the DB for table bloat on a DB of e.g. 3TB in size and e.g. 300.000 tables?

My first idea would be to schedule a job that in a loop issues `pgstattuple(oid)` for each table, each table in a new transaction to not have this be a long running transaction that causes troubles. However, having to full table scan the whole DB for this every week seems wrong. So an approach that analyzes all tables if last analyze is older than a week and then using one of the analyze-data based queries seems better? Maybe using `pgstattuple_approx` is best practice?

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but why do you have so many small tables? (10MB average) And why such an extremely complex data model? 300 tables is complex but still something that someone can understand, but 300.000?

Comment: it's mainly table partitions. and yes, we are moving to reduce the count, but this is what we are at.

Comment: We also use partitioning, but the average size is about 50GB for each partition. Besides the empty partitions for future usage. I would first reduce the number of tables before I would focus on table bloat. How would you maintain a 100.000 tables with 1MB of bloat each? That's a 100GB, about 3% of your database.

Comment: "BUT that seems to be out of favour nowadays."  How can we address anonymous vague rumors?

Comment: I would start dropping 95 to 99 percent of all tables. You would still have 15.000 to 3000 tables to monitor and maintain, but it gives you a reasonable number of tables for a single database (cluster?). When this is a busy database, and your worries about bloat seem to point in that direction, transaction wraparound is a much bigger risk. And with 300.000 tables you get into trouble really fast and it's hard to solve with so many tables. To avoid bloat, mostly caused by updates, you can optimize the fill factor for both tables and indexes.

Comment: TY @FrankHeikens for your valuable input. You are also correct about the transaction wraparound topic being an issue with so many objects. However, for this question I would like to hear from you how you keep table bloat in check. How often do you check for bloat and how do you check it? Automated? Manually? What queries? `pgstattuple_approx` runs only for 7 minutes for 550.000 tables so seems to be a solid pick.

Comment: @Peter The last time I checked for table bloat is over 10 years ago. For updates we aim for HOT by setting a lower fill factor (we introduce bloat!) and for deletes we drop entire table partitions if possible. Never had any issues